# Reopen Impression Class from Impressionist Gem in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, monkeypatching

I'm trying to modify the Impressionist gem class "Impression" to no avail.

I've tried the following:

```
class Impression
  def hello
    "world"
  end
end

Impression.class_eval do
end
```

both in:
/app/models/impression.rb 
and 
/lib/impression.rb     (with correct configuration to include this folder)

What am I doing wrong?  I'm using Rails 4. Ideally, I'd like to add an active record association and add some helper methods.

Comment: What is the error message or failure that you get? Could you also show how you attempt to use these modifications? The first attempt is valid Ruby no matter what, the second is valid provided `Impression` has been defined beforehand. However the `Impression` class may not be taking the role you think it is taking within your Rails app.

Comment: It's just a standard error message that says hello does not exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're overriding a class provided by a gem, you will need to manually require your version to get your changes included. This is usually done in an initializer.

Comment: Do you mind providing an example or clarifying? Would I just define the class in lib/impression.rb, then require 'lib/impression.rb' in confing/initializers/impression.rb

Comment: @ckarbass You can define the class anywhere in your load path (I would use `app/models` because thats where it is in the gem) and then require it in an initializer (eg. `require 'impression'`).

Comment: I tried similar thing since I want to override the Impression class. I am using Rails 3 and this solution didn't work for me. Did you do any additional configurations?

Comment: @sevenseacat Can you give an example of how it can be done. I have recently asked a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41375189/unable-to-add-impressionist-model-to-solr) to link impressionist model with **solr**.

Answer (score 1):

i assume that you are talking about this gem: https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist
and want to change the model class [Impression](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist/blob/master/app/models/impression.rb).

from what i can see it is supposed to be a rails engine.

rails engines use to be namespaced, a stack-trace might have revealed this.

did you try this?

```
# app/extensions/impressionist/impression.rb
module Impressionist
  class Impression
    def hello
      "world"
    end
  end
end
```

you could also try putting your code in an initializer, because it might also be a load order problem.

Comment: for debugging purposes, open the gem, put this on top of the file `puts caller` or raise an exception. that way you can see if and when the class is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
require Impressionist::Engine.root.join('lib/impressionist/models/active_record/impression')

class Impression
  def hello
    "world"
  end
end
```

Comment: ok its confusing there are several classes defined, please check the updated answer

Comment: does it matter where impression.rb (my extension) is? I'll try it again.

Answer (score 1):

Extending a model class with your own methods should be done using a [concern](http://signalvnoise.com/posts/3372-put-chubby-models-on-a-diet-with-concerns).  Try putting this in a file in your `lib` folder and require it in an initializer:

```
require Impressionist::Engine.root.join('lib/impressionist/models/active_record/impression')

module ImpressionExtensions
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def some_instance_method
    # do some stuff
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def some_class_method
      # do some stuff
    end
  end

end

Impression.send(:include, ImpressionExtensions)
```

Adding methods to any model should be done in a similar manner.  The way Impressionist works is a bit different, in that it first defines the Impression class as a regular, standalone class, before overriding it and making it a model.